# SQL Query Returning Unwanted Results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I must be setting up the `And/OR` portion of my query incorrectly.  In the sample dataset below, after filtering out the criteria in my `Where` clause only `FR ni23` should be returned, however my query returns

```
resonance   userid<br>
Del         er12<br>
NULL        em23<br>
Samit       ra23<br>
            em23<br>
FR          ni23<br>
```

This is the syntax I attempted, but is not accurate, where does the problem lie, and what should I change to fix?

```
Declare @T1 Table (resonance varchar(100), userid varchar(10))

Insert Into @T1 (resonance, userid) Values
('Del', 'er12'), (NULL, 'em23'), ('Samit', 'ra23'), 
(NULL, 'axel'), ('', 'em23'), ('', 'red'), ('FR', 'ni23')

Select *
FROM @T1
WHERE userid LIKE '%[0-9]%'
AND (resonance <> 'DEL' OR resonance IS NULL OR resonance <> 'Samit')
```

Comment: Just this is always true: `resonance <> 'DEL' OR resonance <> 'Samit'` because if resonance is DEL then it's not Samit.

Comment: Correct, I want to exclude where resonance equals either which is why I went with the or

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - changing to AND returns 0 results.

Comment: Did you see that I changed IS NULL to NOT NULL? Anyway this seems more compact: `resonance NOT IN ('Del', 'Samit', '')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But still returns the record where resonance = ''

```
Select *
FROM @T1
WHERE userid LIKE '%[0-9]%'
    AND resonance not in ('DEL','Samit')
```

You should define it as:

```
Select *
FROM @T1
WHERE userid LIKE '%[0-9]%'
    AND resonance not in ('DEL','Samit','')
```